# Binary numbers with Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary, hex, ghci

I know it is possible with Haskell to pass values in octal with `0o777` and Hexadecimal with `0x1FF` but:

**Is it possible to pass a value in binary with Haskell?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with the `{-# LANGUAGE BinaryLiterals #-}` extension, as `0b01101`. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/29b2jj/ghc_710_gains_xbinaryliterals_language_syntax/) for some more details.

Comment: I really hope that extension gets in the next Haskell Report. It's obviously a good idea.

Comment: To enable in `ghci`, add `:set -XBinaryLiterals` in your `~/.ghci` config